# How can I change the input dataset in Shiny R?

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I would like to select some rows of a dataset given an input defined by the user. In this case I would like to run different classification trees depending on the different positions in the field. I have a selectInput() in Shiny R which expands a menu where you can select for which field position you want to run the tree. However, for the moment it only runs for all the positions but not for each one individually. I'd appreciate some help on how to switch between datasets depending on user selection.

server.R

```
library(shiny)
library("rpart")
library("party")
library("partykit")

setwd("~/UNIVERSIDAD/EUR/Block 2/Machine Learning/Shiny App Both")
dat <- read.csv("Voetballers.csv")
dat <- dat[,3:20]


shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

 observe({
    if(input$position=="All"){
     dat <- dat
    }
   else if(input$position=="Forward"){
     dat <- dat[dat$Position=="Forward",]
   }
   else if(input$position=="Midfielder"){
     dat <- dat[dat$Position=="Midfielder",]
   }
   else if(input$position=="Defender"){
     dat <- dat[dat$Position=="Defender",]
   }
   else if(input$position=="Goalkeeper"){
     dat <- dat[dat$Position=="Goalkeeper",]
   }
  })

  output$independent <- renderUI({
    checkboxGroupInput("independent", "Independent Variables:",names(dat)[!names(dat) %in% input$dependent],names(dat)[!names(dat) %in% input$dependent])
  })


runRegression <- reactive({
  ctree(as.formula(paste(input$dependent," ~ ",paste(input$independent,collapse="+"))),data=dat)
})
runRegression2 <- reactive({
  rpart(as.formula(paste(input$dependent," ~ ",paste(input$independent,collapse="+"))),data=dat)
})
output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
  plot(runRegression())})
output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
  plot(as.party(runRegression2()))})

})
```